# How Expand a menuitem inside a Button in ExtJS 5.1.0.107

Tags: javascript, extjs5

I am trying to expand the menuitem present in a button using the following snippet

var comp = button.doExpandMenu();

But it seems that submenu is not being rendered in UI. In previous versions of ExtJS button.activate() used to render the submenus.

Do we have an alternative to that in the ExtJS 5.1.0.107 ?

[image]

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2724

Comment: can you please provide your sencha fiddle or code so I can check ?

Comment: @Njdhv I have attached the fiddle

Comment: Are you using modern or classic ?

Comment: Where is your code you have putted same file from [here](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/api/src/Item.js-1.html)